# Display information from Backbone.js related objects

Tags: django, django-models, backbone.js, tastypie, backbone-relational

What is the best way to display information from related objects on my Backbone.js wired front-end when on the backend these attributes are stored on separate Django models in a PostgreSQL database?

I am currently using Django, Tastypie, Django-Tastypie, Backbone.js, Backbone-Relational and Handlebars.js templates. I am open to doing things differently and I am willing to learn new technologies such as Riak if it's necessary or more efficient.

On the front-end what I'm trying to do would be very simple with standard Django templates: display a list of tags on a post and the author of that post.

On the back-end I have a `Post` model and `Tag`, `User` and `UserProfile` (author) models. `Users` and `UserProfiles` are 1-to-1, `Post` has a relation to `UserProfile` but what I want to display is stored on the `User` model under the attribute `username`. At the moment this involves two painstaking lookups to get the author's username for every post. The `Post` model:

```python
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    content = models.TextField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
```

In Coffeescript I have my Backbone models. At present I am trying to fetch the relevant author and tag objects when a Post model is initialized. My current code is very sloppy and I apologize, my javascript foo is still under development!

```coffee
class User extends Backbone.RelationalModel
class UserProfile extends Backbone.RelationalModel
    urlRoot : '/api/v1/profile/?format=json'
class PostTag extends Backbone.RelationalModel
    initialize: ->
        this.get('tag').on 'change', ( model ) =>
            this.get( 'post' ).trigger( 'change:tag', model )
class Tag extends Backbone.RelationalModel
    urlRoot: '/api/v1/tag/?format=json'
    idAttribute: 'id',
    relations: [{
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        key: 'post_tags',
        relatedModel: PostTag,
        reverseRelation: {
            key: 'tag',
            includeInJSON: 'id',
        },
    }],

class Post extends Backbone.RelationalModel
    idAttribute: 'id',
    relations: [{
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        key: 'post_tags',
        relatedModel: PostTag,
        reverseRelation: {
            key: 'post',
            includeInJSON: 'id',
        },
    }]
    initialize: ->
        @.get('tags').forEach(@addTag, @)
        @.addAuthor()
        @.on 'change:tag', (model) ->
            console.log('related tag=%o updated', model)
    addAuthor: () ->
        profile_id = @.get('author')
        if app.UserProfiles.get(profile_id)?
            profile = app.UserProfiles.get(profile_id)
            user = app.Users.get(profile.user)
            @.set('author_name',user.get('username'))
        else
            profile = new app.UserProfile(profile_id)
            app.UserProfiles.add(profile)
            profile.fetch(success: (model,response) =>
                user_id = profile.get('user')
                if app.Users.get(user_id)?
                    user = app.Users.get(user_id)
                    user.fetch(success: (model,response) =>
                        console.log(user.get('username'))
                        @.set('author_name',user.get('username'))
                    )
                    console.log("Existing user"+user_id)
                    console.log(user.get('username'))
                    #@.set('author_name',user.get('username'))
                else
                    user = new app.User('resource_uri':user_id)
                    app.Users.add(user)
                    console.log("New user"+user_id)
                    user.fetch(success: (model,response) =>
                        console.log(user.get('username'))
                        @.set('author_name',user.get('username'))
                    )
            )

    addTag: (tag_id) ->
        console.log(tag_id)
        if app.Tags.get(tag_id)?
            tag = app.Tags.get(tag_id)
            console.log("TAG" + tag)
        else
            console.log("NON EXISTENT")
            console.log(tag_id)
            tag = new app.Tag({'id':tag_id})
            tag.fetch()
            app.Tags.add(tag)
        post_tag = new app.postTag({
            'tag': tag_id,
            'post': @.get('resource_uri')
            })
        @.get('post_tags').add(post_tag)
```

This code actually works fine for fetching and storing the related objects but it's incredibly messy and I'm sure there must be a better way. Further, I can't figure out a way to access the stored tag names to display in my `Handlebars.js` templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing this I found the related question [How do I load sub-models with a foreign key relationship in Backbone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502614/how-do-i-load-sub-models-with-a-foriegn-key-relationship-in-backbone-js)

Since I'd already written the question I figured I may as well post it in case it's useful for anyone.

The answer was as simple as adding `full=True` to my `tastypie` resources. I could then get rid of the `addTags` and `addAuthor` functions and since I don't need to save or update the related objects the rest of the answer in the above thread wasn't necessary for me.